# Using Multiple Languages in your Daily Life or Job

Tags: multiple-languages

What are some ways that you can include the languages you have learned in your daily life and job? and what are some job where you could apply all the languages you know?

I know spanish(native), english, portuguese, some french, and some chinese.

Comment: This question seems opinion-based unless we know your lifestyle. Please expand your question with more details so that the answerers did not guess and try suggesting something that is totally non-applicable to your 'daily life and job'.

Comment: It's the same tools that one uses to learn the language. Read books, watch movies, talk to colleagues who are native speakers. Participate in language exchange forums and make friends with people who speak natively the language(s) you are learning.

Comment: This question is incredibly broad. It's also probably impossible to be extensive--any list someone comes up with can easily have new things added to it. I'm afraid this isn't a good fit for this site. If you have a more specific question--perhaps a specific challenge you're facing with regard to using multiple languages, that would make for a better question.